# StencilJs: nested stencil component doesn't work with events, such as 'click'

Tags: stenciljs

I have a stenciljs component that has a nested stenciljs component:

```
<c-button-group>
   <c-button></c-button>
</c-button-group>
```

In c-button-group template, I'm not using a slot and instead I'm using @Element() private element: HTMLElement to get all the nested elements after I render them in a loop.

```
@Component({
  tag: 'c-button-group'
})
export class CButtonGroup {
  @Element() private element: HTMLElement

  render() {
    return (
      Array.from(this.element.children)
        .map((child) => {
          const el = child as ButtonInterface
          return <c-button variant="grouped">{el.textContent}</c-button>
        })
    )
  }
}
```

The reason why i use loop because i have to add attribute **variant="grouped"** for each nested element and i want to add it here, in the template. So this works but i noticed that if i assign a **click event handler** it doesn't work.

```
<body>
 <c-button-group>
   <c-button id="cBtn" @click="btnClickHandler">Years</c-button>   
 </c-button-group>


 <script>
   document.querySelector('#cBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
     console.log('Years')
   })
 </script>
</body>
```

Click event above doesn't work.

*And seems this is obvious because in the render function **i create a new 'c-button' based on a nested c-button**.*

My question is how do I pass all events that were assigned from the nested component to the new component that was created in the render function?

PS:

I noticed that if i use on-click attribute without a value to new c-button element, click event works:

```
 Array.from(this.element.children)
        .map((child) => {
          const el = child as ButtonInterface
          return <c-button 
                   variant="grouped"
                   on-click
                 >{el.textContent}</c-button>
        })
```

I just added **on-click** and it started working but in console i started getting errors:
*TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': parameter 2 is not of type 'Object'.*

So at first this is not an option because i am getting that error and at second what if i need not only 'click' event, maybe there will be 5 or 10 events, so in that case i will have to add them all manually, not very comfortable to say the least.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `outerHTML` and `innerHTML`

```js
render() {
    return (
      Array.from(this.element.children)
        .map((child) => {
          child.setAttribute('variant', 'grouped')
          return <div innerHTML={child.outerHTML}></div>
        })
    )
  }
```

However this will only be able to pass events which are attached by attribute instead of `addEventListener`, as `outerHTML` is a string

```html
<c-button-group>
   <c-button id="cBtn" onclick="btnClickHandler()">Years</c-button>   
 </c-button-group>
```

Here `btnClickHandler` will work for rendered children elements

Comment: Thank you for you anwser! Yes, this is one of the solution but also has restrictions because, for example, that will not work in VueJs.

<c-button-group>
      <c-button @click="btnClickHandler">Years</c-button>
</c-button-group>

I've checked why, child element doesn't get 'onclick' as attribute in VueJs. So this is a big restrictions for me to create elements using innerHTML :(

Answer (score 0):

So the only way i found myself is to use `<slot />` and `@Element() private element: HTMLElement` together.

```
@Element() private element: HTMLElement

componentWillLoad() {
  Array.from(this.element.children).forEach(el => {
    el.setAttribute('variant', 'grouped')  
  })
}

render() {
  return <slot />
}
```

Using `<slot />` allows as to use all events and using `this.element.children` gives the ability to edit DOM elements before their rendering, we can remove, add any attribute, class, and so on...